# How to run from terminal a JMeter script that actually stops?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Without digging into implementation details about the requests, I have a question about the configuration of the Thread Groups.
My JMeter script runs from terminal (Non GUI) while having the Thread Group set as follows:

- Loop Count: Infinite
- Duration: 20 seconds

After adding a **setUp Thread Group** that is set with 1 Thread and 1 Loop, the script will never stop (behaving as it would be infinite loop). If I set the **setUp Thread Group** similar to the main Thread Group (Infinite and x number of seconds) the script will respect the x number of seconds but the problem is that it will run the **setUp Thread Group** multiple times, and I need to run the **setUp Thread Group**  once only, as it sets stuff in the database.
I tried various suggestions from various articles, like setting runtime vars:

- -Jjmeterthread.0.loops=1
- -Jiterations=1
- -Jgroup1.threads=1

but none would work.
In conclusion, anyone can suggest a way of configuring the **setUp Thread Group** so that it only runs once before the main Thread Group?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it happened for me to find a JMeter bug... the defect was leaked in the release 5.6 but it was fixed in the hotfix 5.6.1. More details [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/issues/6008).

If anyone gets into this, upgrade from 5.6 to next, and enjoy.